# Why does json_decode without assoc work different on PHP 5.6 and PHP 7.2

Tags: php, json, isset

i have now spen hours to analyse arrays on different servers.

my little code:

```
echo "Current PHP version: " . phpversion() . "\r\n";

$return = '{"status":"ok","message":"","code":"200","data":{"1234":{"sid":1,"name":"foo"},"4321":{"sid":2,"name":"bar"}}}';
$nr = "1234";

$json_data = json_decode($return, true);
$data = $json_data['data'];
if(isset($data[$nr])){
    echo "$nr found.\r\n";
}else{
    echo "$nr not found.\r\n";
}


$json_data = json_decode($return);
$data = (array) $json_data->data;
if(isset($data[$nr])){
    echo "$nr found.\r\n";
}else{
    echo "$nr not found.\r\n";
}
```

Produces different output:

```
Current PHP version: 7.2.0
1234 found.
1234 found.
```

```
Current PHP version: 5.6.8
1234 found.
1234 not found.
```

so why is:

```
$json_data = json_decode($return, true);
$data = $json_data['data'];
```

not the same as

```
$json_data = json_decode($return);
$data = (array) $json_data->data;
```

on Servers with PHP 5.6

on both is $data an array, but on PHP 5.6 the isset does not work
on the array properly.

Comment: I think because (array) only casts the top-level to an array, not the 2nd level (they stay objects)

Comment: and I can see no difference in the php versions: https://3v4l.org/nMRKo

Comment: on 7.2 the array key is not a String. ?

Comment: true, I didn't see that. There is explanations in the linked/duped question!